# Realizar ordenação por um determinado campo de uma determinada tabela

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server, expressões-lambda

Tenho a seguinte sintaxe

A instrução abaixo realizar a ordenação pelo campo **Numero Lote** da Tabela **Lote**

**var lvmLotes = db.Lotes.ToList().Where(x => x.DataAbate.Date == Pesquisa).OrderBy(x => x.NumeroLote);**

[image: Base de dados indicando campo que atualmente ordena e campo que quero que ordene]

Estou precisando mudar o campo que ordene a lista, como faço para realizar a ordenação através do campo **Sequencia Inicial** da tabela **Gênero**

Comment: Como assim? Você precisa que na hora da visualização, a SequenciaInicial venha primeiro que a DataAbate?

Comment: Isto que que Ordene por DataAbate e também por Sequencia Incial, na hora da visualização, no return View(loteViewModel); da ActionResult -- public ActionResult Index(DateTime? Pesquisa)

Comment: Adicione SequenciaInicial no seu código. Já tentou?

Comment: Já tentei e o lambda não tem acesso, e assim parece que tenho de acessar  LoteGenero depois Genero e ai sim tem acesso ao campo SequenciaInicial

Comment: @MariaClara eu já tentei adicionar SequenciaInicial, var lvmLotes = db.Lotes.ToList().Where(x => x.DataAbate.Date == Pesquisa).OrderBy(x => x.NumeroLote).ThenBy(c => c.SequenciaInicial); mas não funcionou